# Allow Dokan vendors to purchase their own product in WooCommerce

Tags: vendor, dokan

I need to let the Dokan vendors to buy their products, at a production price. The vendors upload digital files and the clients buy printed products based on their digital files, but I need that vendors can also buy the printed products, at a production cost (which should not generate earnings for vendors). There is possible?

I found a solution on the internet, but the sales generate earnings for vendors
Here is the context of this problem
[Avoid Dokan vendors to purchase their own product in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76468732/avoid-dokan-vendors-to-purchase-their-own-product-in-woocommerce/77605491#77605491)